# School management software on Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, education

Can anybody suggest software that runs on Ubuntu to manage a high school.  Software would need to hold a database of students as well as generating reports based on marks entered.

Please provide links

Comment: I do not understand why is this question marked as too broad. Software with a students database and capable of reporting is a pretty narrow request.

Comment: This is niche software.  As such I asked the question here as a general search turned up few options. The fact that there has only been 1 answer so far I would think demonstrates that it is not too broad

Comment: @LuísdeSousa as long as the question is a pool instead answers where each answer is equally valid, it's too broad. Duncan, I recommend you instead Software Recommendations, [but instead provide a very specific set of requirements.](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) There your question will be well received.

Comment: What do you mean by "the question is a pool instead"?

Comment: To me this sounds like a website and not software....

Comment: Needs more detailed requirements.

Answer (score 8):

SchoolTool is a suite of free administrative software for schools. Since it can be installed easily and used with no licensing fees, SchoolTool can be used by schools for a single purpose, by individual teachers or small teams within schools, or as a whole-school comprehensive student information system, encompassing demographics, gradebooks, attendance, calendars and reporting.

**Overview of Features**

The standard installation of SchoolTool includes:

- Customizable student and teacher demographics and other personal
  data;
- Contact management for teachers, students, and their guardians;
- Teacher gradebooks;
- Skill and outcomes based assessment;
- Schoolwide assessment data collection and report card generation;
- Class attendance and daily participation grades;
- Calendars for the school, groups, individuals, and resource booking;
- Tracking and management of student interventions.

Resources:

- [Home page](http://schooltool.org)
- [Project on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/schooltool-project)
- [Documentation](http://book.schooltool.org/)
- [Developer tools](http://source.schooltool.org)

[image]

To install it:

```
sudo apt-get install schooltool
```

**ENJOY!!!**